# Where is ExampleData stored on my system

Tags: curated-data, files-and-directories

When I enter:

```
Import["ExampleData/numberdata.csv"]
```

Where does Mathematica go on my system to find the file numberdata.csv?

Or, what Mathematica command will assist in answering this question?

Answer (score 6):

`FindFile["ExampleData/numberdata.csv"]` will give you the answer for this, or just about any other file `Import` could locate.